# Incomplete Plinko board, What is it the correct probability?

Tags: probability, games

Suppose I have an Plinko board, there are 2 pegs missing `(2,1)` and `(1,1)` supposing we are counting `(0,0)`:

[image]

I want to know the probability of a chip to get from **A** to **A'** (first space)
as shown on figure.

As my understanding There are **3 success cases**:

[image]

So the probability that chip gets to hole `A'` given it was send from `A` space is `5/8` because the probability is the **sum of all success cases**

However, what happens if we assume the **red stick** does not matter, because if chip goes to the left, it will have the same path as if we have gone right path, and the only peg that "decides" is the **green one**.

[image]

So if the chip goes left it will have a probability, but in all **2** cases it won't matter and the green stick will be the one that decides if chip goes from **A** to **A'** or **B'**
in which case `p=0.5`

What is the correct Probability `0.5` or `0.625` And why?

Well, to check it out, I made execution of a program and 
I am getting

```
run   result
1     6,270/10000 
2     6,232/10000
3     6,104/10000
4     6,293/10000
5     6,270/10000
6     6,241/10000
```

So I guess `P=0.625`...

Comment: Hint: enumerate all possible paths originating at A.

Comment: I did, And there are 3 right?

Comment: Okay--and what are their individual chances of occurring?  I see you have already done this work and posted it.  You scarcely need a simulation then: you obtained a good answer.

Comment: Someone said probability is 0.5, and we differed... I wanted to make sure I am correct, I guess there is not too much to say with the example I posted